# I can't stop setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var radiobuttons = $('input[name="slider"]');
    radiobuttons.eq(0).prop( "checked", true );
    var defalutvar = 0;

   function ani(a) {             
    function animate() {        
    var currentbutton = radiobuttons.eq(a);
        currentbutton.prop( "checked", true );
        a = (a + 1) % radiobuttons.length; //0, then 1, then 2, then 0, then 1, then 2, then 0, ...
    }        
    var rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate,1000);
    }

    $( document ).ready(ani(defalutvar)); 


    $('#active label').click(function () {            
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios); 
    });
```

<s>This is my code. I created a function ani to set a starting variable for a loop.
Now i can't stop setInterval. Someone can help me?</s>

**Update:**

```
    var radiobuttons = $('input[name="slider"]');
    radiobuttons.eq(0).prop( "checked", true );
    var defalutvar = 0;
    var negative = -1;

   function ani(a) {             
    function animate() {        
    var currentbutton = radiobuttons.eq(a);
        currentbutton.prop( "checked", true );
        a = (a + 1) % radiobuttons.length; //0, then 1, then 2, then 0, then 1, then 2, then 0, ...
    }
         var rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate,1000);
         $('#active label').click(function () {            
            clearInterval(rollDemRadios);  
        });
    }

    ani(0); 


    $('#active label').click(function () {
        i = $('input[name="slider"]:checked').index();
        ani(i);            
   });
```

Sorry. I will say clearly my idea. I am coding an java-based autoplay for a css-only slider. It will autoplay first then when I click a node it would stop and refresh with a new starting variable. My code is not working correctly, it continuouses at old position that it was running. It is my real problem. Sorry all.

Comment: This is because you have declared it inside a function and trying to clear it in another

Comment: declare variable on any outer common scope

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Comment: Updated my problem. Sorry all...

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're doing it [in Javascript, not Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

Second, this is locally scoped:

```
var rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate,1000);
```

meaning it exists only within the context of the `animate` function.

To fix it, declare it globally and then just assign it a value inside the `animate` function. So, at the top of the code where you're declaring other variables, put this:

```
var rollDemRadios;
```

and then instead of:

```
var rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate,1000);
```

put just:

```
rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate,1000);
```

---

### POST-UPDATE

The main problem is that you have two click event listener on `#active label` and when you click, it does clear the current interval, but it also creates a new one because it calls `ani(i);`. Not only that, but by calling `ani(i);` you're also creating a new set of listeners, which keep piling up and might cause your page to hang after a while. I'd suggest refactoring the `ani` function. Something like this:

```js
var radiobuttons = $('input[name="slider"]');
radiobuttons.eq(0).prop("checked", true);
var defalutvar = 0;
var negative = -1;
var rollDemRadios;

function ani(a) {
  function animate() {
    var currentbutton = radiobuttons.eq(a);
    currentbutton.prop("checked", true);
    a = (a + 1) % radiobuttons.length; //0, then 1, then 2, then 0, then 1, then 2, then 0, ...
  }
  rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate, 1000);

}

ani(0);

$('#active label').click(function() {
  if (rollDemRadios) {
    clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    rollDemRadios = false;
    $('#on').removeClass('active');
    $('#off').addClass('active');
  } else {
    i = $('input[name="slider"]:checked').index();
    ani(i);
    $('#off').removeClass('active');
    $('#on').addClass('active');
  }
});

// irrelevant styling
$('#on').addClass('active');
```

```css
#on.active {color: green}
#off.active {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider">
</div>
<div id="active">
  <label>Toggle <span id="on">On</span>/<span id="off">Off</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

variable `rollDemRadios` to be declared as global scoped variable as shown below, otherwise variable `rollDemRadios` is considered as `undefined` within `clearInterval(rollDemRadios);`

```
    var radiobuttons = $('input[name="slider"]');
    radiobuttons.eq(0).prop("checked", true);
    var defalutvar = 0;
    var rollDemRadios = null;

    function ani(a) {
        function animate() {
            var currentbutton = radiobuttons.eq(a);
            currentbutton.prop("checked", true);
            a = (a + 1) % radiobuttons.length; //0, then 1, then 2, then 0, then 1, then 2, then 0, ...
        }
        rollDemRadios = setInterval(animate, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(ani(defalutvar));


    $('#active label').click(function () {
        clearInterval(rollDemRadios);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var radiobuttons = $('input[name="slider"]');
    radiobuttons.eq(0).prop( "checked", true );
    //var defalutvar = 0; //is never used
    //var negative = -1; //is never used

   var rollDemRadios;
   function ani(a) {                 
      rollDemRadios = setInterval(function() {
        var currentbutton = radiobuttons.eq(a);
        currentbutton.prop( "checked", true );
        a = (a + 1) % radiobuttons.length;
      },1000);
    }

    $('#active label').click(function () {            
       clearInterval(rollDemRadios);  
    });
    ani(0); 


    $('#active label').click(function () {
        i = $('input[name="slider"]:checked').index();
        ani(i);            
   });
```

[The doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to help you how to use `setInterval`.